# Weird behavior of ExecuteQuery() - "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, csom

Until last Friday I was using the following powershell script to manipulate lists on Sharepoint Online using CSOM with no problems.

```
$spOcredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($spOuser, $secpasswd)
$spOctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($spOSiteURL)
$spOctx.Credentials = $spOcredentials

$spOList = $spOctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($spOListName)
$spOctx.Load($spOList)
$spOctx.Load($spOList.Fields)
$spOctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

The script is based on this [article](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-get-all-list-fields-using-powershell.html)

Yesterday I found out that the script stopped working and the call to ExecuteQuery() returns an error:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\Develop\Kontrola sloupcu seznamu.ps1:36 char:1
+ $spOctx.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

I searched for what kind of error it is and how to prevent it, but I didn't find a relevant solution.

Today, purely by accident, I came up with a way to make the script work. When I call ExecuteQuery() twice, the first one ends up with the above error, but the second one runs fine.
I'm confused by this and it certainly doesn't feel like a clean solution.

Comment: Check to see if credentials are valid.  You may have a temporary credential that expired after 30 days (or similar).  Or the website URI is no longer valid.

Comment: Credentials and URI are valid. This is a site I own, so I should know about the URI change.
Additionally, it wouldn't explain why the first ExecuteQuery() ends up with an error and the second one on the next line runs correctly.

Comment: The credentials need to be verified by a password server.  There may be a delay getting the credentials causing the error.  Once the credentials are verified to code works.

Comment: Check for recent changes in the schema of the list. That said, consider using [PnP.Powershell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/), your scripts will be easier to write (especially regarding the authentication.